# Add element to document and then remove it using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, element

I am adding text to an element in Jquery using

```
$('.alert-saved').append('<br /><a href="/?similar=' + release_id  + '&source=index">See more like this >></a>')
```

I then show this to the user and pause.

```
$('.alert-saved').delay(5000).fadeOut(2000);
```

I would now like to remove all the text I appended.

I have tried this but it didn't work

```
$('.alert-saved').remove('<br /><a href="/?similar=' + release_id  + '&source=index">See more like this >></a>')
```

Comment: You can add it into a tag with particular class , you can select it easily when you want to remove it .

Comment: @Franco check below given code I hope it will work as per your requirement

Comment: checkout my demo below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass an empty [`HTML`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) string argument:

```
$('.alert-saved').html('');
```

**EDIT 1**

If you need to keep other elements, you can use this method:

```js
var newLine = jQuery('<br /><a href="#your whatever">See more like this</a>');
jQuery(".alert-saved").append(newLine);
setTimeout(function() {
  jQuery(newLine).remove();
}, 2000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="alert-saved">
  <span>I wanna stay!</span>
</p>
```

Comment: there is actually other text I wish to retain already in the element

Comment: consider my suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to :

```
$('.alert-saved').append('<div id="divId"><br /><a href="/?similar=' + release_id  + '&source=index">See more like this >></a></div>');
```

And while removing you can use :

```
$('.alert-saved').remove('#divId');
```

With the help of `divId` you can easily remove your appended element/string from `'.alert-saved'`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code it will work as expected -

```js
$('.alert-saved').append('<div class="testing" <br /><a href="/?similar=' + 'release_id'  + '&source=index">See more like this >></a> </div>')

$('.alert-saved').delay(5000).fadeOut(2000);

$('.alert-saved').remove('.testing')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert-saved"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this also :

```
$('.alert-saved').next().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your element in an tagged element with a class, or a custom tag, and then delete it accordingly like:

```
var release_id = 'demo'
$('.alert-saved').append('<div class="added"><br /><a href="/?similar=' + release_id + '&source=index">See more like this >></a></div>')

setTimeout(function() {
  $('.alert-saved>.added').remove();
}, 5000);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Lxy83r43/

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you append append with a class  like this and remove all at once using `.remove()`

Checkout the demo below

```js
$('.yes').click(function(){
$('.alert-saved').append('<div class ="added" ><br /><a href="/?&source=index">See more like this >></a>');
})


$('.me').click(function(){
$('.added').remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="alert-saved">

asdasdasdas

</div>

<input type="button" class="me" value="remove"/>
<input type="button" class="yes" value="add"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this work is adding `class` or `id` to appended element.

But if you don't want to do this, you can store new elements in variable and append it using [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) to html document like this:

```
var HTML = $("<br><a>New link</a>");
$(HTML).appendTo('.alert-saved');
```

When you want to remove elements, use bottom code.

```
HTML.remove();
```

```js
var HTML = $("<br><a>New link</a>");
$(HTML).appendTo('.alert-saved');
setTimeout(function(){
    HTML.remove();
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert-saved">
    <a>Old link</a>
</div>
```